# I can't launch gitlab-ce with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ce

I want to install GitLab on my computer and learn Docker.

When I use

```
docker run --hostname monlogiciel.com --publish 443:443 --publish 8000:80 --publish 22:22 --name gitlab --volume ~/dev/docker/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab --volume ~/dev/docker/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab --volume ~/dev/docker/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

It works : I can connect to http://monlogiciel:8000/ and Gitlab is here.

my `/etc/hosts` contains

```
127.0.0.1       localhost monlogiciel.com
```

However, when I want to use `docker-compose up -d`, it doesn't work.

This is my docker-compose :

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  gitlab:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
    restart: always
    hostname: 'monlogiciel.com'
    ports:
      - '8000:80'
      - '443:443'
      - '22:22'
    volumes:
      - '~/dev/docker/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
      - '~/dev/docker/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
      - '~/dev/docker/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
```

What's wrong with that ?

Here is the logs

```
gitlab_1  | ==> /var/log/gitlab/unicorn/unicorn_stderr.log <==
```

gitlab_1  | I, [2017-09-29T10:09:40.311993 #1493]  INFO -- : listening on addr=127.0.0.1:8080 fd=19
gitlab_1  | F, [2017-09-29T10:09:40.314300 #1493] FATAL -- : error adding listener addr=/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket
gitlab_1  | Errno::ENAMETOOLONG: File name too long - connect(2) for /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket
gitlab_1  |   /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn/socket_helper.rb:122:in `initialize'
gitlab_1  |   /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn/socket_helper.rb:122:in`new'
gitlab_1  |   /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn/socket_helper.rb:122:in `bind_listen'
gitlab_1  |   /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:231:in`listen'
gitlab_1  |   /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:808:in `block in bind_new_listeners!'
gitlab_1  |   /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:808:in`each'
gitlab_1  |   /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:808:in `bind_new_listeners!'
gitlab_1  |   /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:130:in`start'
gitlab_1  |   /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
gitlab_1  |   /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/unicorn:23:in`load'
gitlab_1  |   /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/unicorn:23:in `'
gitlab_1  | 
gitlab_1  | ==> /var/log/gitlab/unicorn/unicorn_stdout.log <==
gitlab_1  | bundler: failed to load command: unicorn (/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/unicorn)
gitlab_1  | 
gitlab_1  | ==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-monitor/current <==
gitlab_1  | 2017-09-29_10:09:41.06751 127.0.0.1 - - [29/Sep/2017:10:09:41 UTC] "GET /sidekiq HTTP/1.1" 200 4177
gitlab_1  | 2017-09-29_10:09:41.06778 - -> /sidekiq
gitlab_1  | 
gitlab_1  | ==> /var/log/gitlab/unicorn/current <==
gitlab_1  | 2017-09-29_10:09:41.34741 failed to start a new unicorn master
gitlab_1  | 2017-09-29_10:09:41.36083 starting new unicorn master
gitlab_1  | 
gitlab_1  | ==> /var/log/gitlab/unicorn/unicorn_stderr.log <==
gitlab_1  | I, [2017-09-29T10:09:42.015787 #1539]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
gitlab_1  | 
gitlab_1  | ==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-monitor/current <==
gitlab_1  | 2017-09-29_10:09:43.35601 127.0.0.1 - - [29/Sep/2017:10:09:42 UTC] "GET /database HTTP/1.1" 200 44957
gitlab_1  | 2017-09-29_10:09:43.35632 - -> /database
gitlab_1  | 2017-09-29_10:09:45.23931 127.0.0.1 - - [29/Sep/2017:10:09:45 UTC] "GET /process HTTP/1.1" 200 457
gitlab_1  | 2017-09-29_10:09:45.23962 - -> /process
gitlab_1  | 2017-09-29_10:09:56.06482 127.0.0.1 - - [29/Sep/2017:10:09:56 UTC] "GET /sidekiq HTTP/1.1" 200 4177
gitlab_1  | 2017-09-29_10:09:56.06511 - -> /sidekiq
gitlab_1  | 
gitlab_1  | ==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log <==
gitlab_1  | Raven 2.5.3 configured not to capture errors: DSN not set
gitlab_1  | 
gitlab_1  | ==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-monitor/current <==
gitlab_1  | 2017-09-29_10:09:58.33464 127.0.0.1 - - [29/Sep/2017:10:09:57 UTC] "GET /database HTTP/1.1" 200 44959
gitlab_1  | 2017-09-29_10:09:58.33492 - -> /database
gitlab_1  | 2017-09-29_10:10:00.23730 127.0.0.1 - - [29/Sep/2017:10:10:00 UTC] "GET /process HTTP/1.1" 200 457
gitlab_1  | 2017-09-29_10:10:00.23766 - -> /process
gitlab_1  | 
gitlab_1  | ==> /var/log/gitlab/unicorn/current <==
gitlab_1  | 2017-09-29_10:10:00.62159 master failed to start, check stderr log for details

Comment: could you please run docker-compose up and see what the logs are saying?

Comment: Your issue is that you have not given any certificates and you are trying to use `https` instead of `http` in compose

Comment: Is it caused by :  `environment:
     GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
      external_url 'https://monlogiciel.com'`

Comment: I try without `environment: GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: | external_url 'https://monlogiciel.com' ` ans it works. Now i have another problem

Comment: When I go to http://monlogiciel.com:8000/ I have GitLab is not responding (502)   **Whoops, GitLab is taking too much time to respond.

Try refreshing the page, or going back and attempting the action again.

Please contact your GitLab administrator if this problem persists.**

Comment: gitlab_1  | F, [2017-09-29T10:09:40.314300 #1493] FATAL -- : error adding listener addr=/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket
gitlab_1  | Errno::ENAMETOOLONG: File name too long - connect(2) for /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by having the gitlab.socket (created and used by unicorn) under a mounted volume path which resolves to a too long host filesystem path.

You can keep the original configuration by just moving the gitlab.socket creation path outside the mounted volume path by modifying the gitlab config **unicorn['socket']**, eg:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  gitlab:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
    restart: always
    hostname: 'monlogiciel.com'
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        unicorn['socket'] = '/opt/gitlab/var/unicorn/gitlab.socket'
    ports:
      - '8000:80'
      - '443:443'
      - '22:22'
    volumes:
      - '~/dev/docker/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
      - '~/dev/docker/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
      - '~/dev/docker/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
```